# How to hide/show text selection controls in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, editor, textselection

I am working with text editor in flutter which is scrollable and whenever there is text selection control in editor, it scrolls along with editor and overlaps all other widgets. Basically what I need to achieve is to hide the text selection controls while scrolling and show it again when scrolling is stopped. The exact implementation can be found on google docs application. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Text selection controls on google docs]